# hbm2ddl.auto set to validate but getting "table or view not found" exception

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, validation, jboss

I am deploying an application on JBoss EAP 6.4, using Oracle as database, under production. It uses Hibernate with the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property set to `validate` in `persistence.xml`. The application starts gracefully and I see all the tables found in JBoss log. The problem is that when I access the application, I get a `ORA-00942: table or view not found` exception.

So, my question is: what exactly means the `validate` option? Shouldn't the eventual absence of a table/view be noticed by Hibernate/JBoss on the application start up process? May that exception be caused by a lack of grant?

PS: as the deploy is being made in production, I don't even know the database user and host, and I don't have access to the deployer right now, to ask that.

Answer (score 0):

**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** has below possible properties.

```
validate | update | create | create-drop | none
```

`validate` - validate the schema, makes no changes to the database. In case of validate, if schema does not exists in DB, it is not created. Instead, it will throw an error.

At server startup, application might not be using any tables as such.